# Get Publication/Poster List

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, multibib

I want to create a list of publications, posters and conference talks with LaTeX. As I can't distinguish these three reference-types by the classical BibTeX types (e.g. article, inbook,...) I though about to create three `.bib` files seperately and include the bibliographies of all three in a LaTeX document. For multiple bibliographies I came across `multibib`, but I can't get my code working:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{jurabib}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%%%%% Articles %%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{art-bib.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {A book},
}
@booklet{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {A booklet},
}
\end{filecontents}

%%%%% Conferences %%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{conf-bib.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {A book Conf},
}
@booklet{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {A booklet Conf},
}
\end{filecontents}


\newcites{art}{Articles}
\newcites{conf}{Conferences}
%\newcites{poster}{Posters}


\bibliographystyleart{jurabib}
\bibliographystyleconf{jurabib}
%\bibliographystyleposter{plain}

\begin{document}

\nociteart{*}
\nociteconf{*}
%\nociteposter{*}


\bibliographyconf{conf-bib.bib}
\bibliographyart{art-bib.bib}

\end{document}
```

I am using Texmaker with TexMaker 3.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying the bib files, use

```
\bibliographyconf{conf-bib}
\bibliographyart{art-bib}
```

Then run `latex` or `pdflatex` on the tex file. This will generate two .aux files, `art.aux` and `conf.aux`. Run `bibtex` on these two files. Finally another latex run will give the desired result.

Comment: running bibtex on both .aux files is the key.