# Thesis publication list

Tags: cross-referencing, thesis

I currently have a list of Publications at the beginning of my thesis in plain text. It looks like this;

```
\chapter*{List of Publications}

This thesis resulted in the following publications;

\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*] %list of publications used as chapters in thesis.
    \item Authors, \textbf{Title}, \textit{Journal}, etc.
    \item Authors, \textbf{Title}, \textit{Journal}, etc.
    \item Authors, \textbf{Title}, \textit{Journal}, etc.
    
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{The author's contribution to these publications;}
In all cases, the author wrote the manuscript. For Publication I bla bla bla...

\newpage
In addition to this thesis, the author has contributed to this publication;

\begin{enumerate}[resume, label=\Roman*]
    \item Authors, \textbf{Title}, \textit{Journal}, etc.
    
\end{enumerate}

The following publications were written prior to the author's PhD... blablabla

\begin{enumerate}[resume, label=\Roman*] %list of publications not in thesis, but referenced regularly.
    \item Authors, \textbf{Title}, \textit{Journal}, etc.
    \item Authors, \textbf{Title}, \textit{Journal}, etc.
    
\end{enumerate}
```

And the document is set up as;

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

\preface
...
\input{0-publications/publications} %list of publications inserted here.
...
\include{chapter}
...
\end{document}
```

Some of the publications listed above form the bulk of a chapter, where others do not.

I'd like a command to refer to each of these in the main text to appear as  **Publication I**. The command could look like `\pub{tag}`. This should also creates a hyperlink to the publication (either where it is included in the thesis body, or to a URL). i.e. within a chapter;

```
As reported in \pub{tag}...
```

Should produce;

[image: What I want!]

But clicking on **Publication I** should take the reader to the included pdf within the thesis *or* the URL where it can be read (if it doesn't form part of the thesis).

I've [seen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97057/including-additional-bibliography-publication-list-in-thesis) [many](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97895/get-publication-poster-list) [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559839/make-publications-section-on-thesis) related to making a separate bibliography, but not sure that this is ideal here.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Can you please add two things via the Edit bitton? 1) Completing your code from `documentclass .. end{document}` to make it easy to copy and run for us? Sometimes it's crucial to know, what you include or miss. Leave out, what's not relevant to reproduce your problem. 2) Make a mock-up drawing or text which better illustrates your desired end-result? Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I know what you want,  but does `\begin{enumerate}[resume, label=\Roman*, ref={Publication \Roman*}]`. Then `\label{foo}` after `\item` and `\ref{foo}` later on do what you want? I assume you're using the enumitem package.

Comment: @frabjous This is helpful, and though is not what I *really* wanted, is more than sufficient for the purpose of my thesis. Thank you!

Comment: What did you *really* want? It's probably possible with a small tweak. I'm just not sure what that is.

Comment: Currently, when I click on e.g. **Publication I**, it takes me to the list of publications, which is good. Instead if (i) when I hover over it it displays the name of Publication I, and (ii) clicking the link takes me to where Publication I is reproduced in the thesis. Hope that makes sense.